# Vagrant - Docker provider on Windows - Rsync fails

Tags: docker, vagrant, boot2docker, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to set up a Dev environment for our next project with **Vagrant + Docker** (as a provdier). I'm working on **Windows 8.1 OS** with **cygwin** (with its ssh and rsync packages).

**Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "."
  end
end
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
#RUN apt-get install -y nodejs=0.6.12~dfsg1-1ubuntu1
RUN mkdir /var/www

ADD app.js /var/www/app.js

CMD ["/usr/bin/node", "/var/www/app.js"]
```

**vagrant up --provider=docker**

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    default: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
    default: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
    default:
    default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/boot2docker'...
    default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' is up to date...
    default: Setting the name of the VM: docker-host_default_1461921660147_65487
    default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 (guest) => 2375 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    default: Booting VM...
    default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.16) and guest (4.3.28 r100309) do not match.
The guest's platform ("tinycore") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.16 - guest version is 4.3.28 r100309
mkdir: can't create directory '/tmp/selfgz98727713': No such file or directory
Cannot create target directory /tmp/selfgz98727713
You should try option --target OtherDirectory
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.16. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
==> default: Syncing folders to the host VM...
    default: Installing rsync to the VM...
    default: The machine you're rsyncing folders to is configured to use
    default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script rsync to automatically
    default: enter this password, so you'll likely be prompted for a password
    default: shortly.
    default:
    default: If you don't want to have to do this, please enable automatic
    default: key insertion using `config.ssh.insert_key`.
    default: Rsyncing folder: /home/Carles/Environment/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_1461921688_64359
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /home/Carles/Environment/
Guest path: /var/lib/docker/docker_1461921688_64359
Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=true -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --exclude .vagrant/ /home/Carles/Environment/ docker@127.0.0.1:/var/lib/docker/docker_1461921688_64359
Error: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

**rsync --version**

```
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, no xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

**vagrant --version**

```
Vagrant 1.8.1
```

**VBox version**

```
Versión 5.0.16 r105871
```

Anybody has found a Win configuration to run successfully a vagrant machine as docker provider without use a Host VM **proxy**?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "Host VM proxy"? To the best of my knowledge, under Windows you will need a virtualization software like VirtualBox or Hyper-V to host a minimal Linux in which the Docker container will run. If using vagrant and experiencing rsync problems, you may want to try the boot2docker vagrant box provided here https://github.com/dduportal/boot2docker-vagrant-box

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head against this one all of Friday, then today found a "Docker Toolbox" (https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) that makes all of the pain go away.  It will even install a light-weight MSYS Git (to get you a bash shell as well) and VirtualBox too if not already installed.

Note that Docker's own web pages mix up the languaging somewhat.  "Docker Toolbox" will install on Windows 7 and beyond.  There's a newer "Docker for Windows" (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) which is Windows 10 Pro or better ONLY, and will prevent you from running any VirtualBox machines because it uses Hyper-V.

Unfortunately, the "old" "Docker Toolbox" used to get called "Docker for Windows" (in places at least), so it's easy mixed messages.  Just be aware of the two different solutions (Win 10 Pro + & Hyper-V **versus** VirtualBox and >= Win 7) and you'll soon work out which one any particular web page is *actually* talking about.

And yes, this is a strategy for getting Docker on Windows to work; I've ended up abandoning Vagrant.